# Why is my code printing rvalue 2 times instead of rvalue & lvalue?

Tags: c++, forward, rvalue, lvalue, stdmove

So I wanted to practice the usage of `std::forward` and created a `Test` class with 2 constructors. 1 with `T&` and the other with `T&&` as overload. `T&` prints *lvalue*, and `T&&` prints *rvalue* so I know which one of the constructors is being used. I create 2 instances of class on stack and to my surprise both of which are using the `T&&` overload.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T> auto forward(T &&t) {
  if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value) {
    return t;
  }
  return std::move(t);
}

template <class T> class Test {
public:
  Test(T &) { std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl; };
  Test(T &&) { std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl; };
};

int main() {
  int x = 5;
  Test<int> a(forward(3));
  Test<int> b(forward(x));
  return 0;
}
```

I tried using the original `std::forward` function and implementing it but both times it printed *rvalue* x2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `auto` is never a reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem stems from the return type of `forward`.  You use `auto` as the return type which will not deduce a reference for you.  That means when you do return, no matter which branch it returns from, you return by value which means you have a prvalue.

What you need is `decltype(auto)` so you return an rvalue or lvalue reference, depending on the return statement.  Using

```
template <class T> decltype(auto) forward(T &&t) {
  if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
    return t;
  else
    return std::move(t);
}
```

gives you the output:

```
rvalue
lvalue
```

Comment: Isn't there such a thing as an `auto&`, or am I making up silliness?

Comment: @Chipster There is, but that will always return an lvalue reference, which would not be what you want in a forwarding function.

Comment: @3l4x You'e welcome.  Good first effort BTW.  Generic code and forwarding can be pretty tough to get right.

Comment: @NathanOliver, even for compilers. ;)